# List is printing oddly in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing

so I am trying to make tictactoe and i'm having trouble with the board. when I make 3 list of the 1-9 spots they print out as a whole list including the brackets and commas, for example ex = [1, 2] and it would print that full thing. I've never had this problem before. Can anyone help and is it because im using an Online IDE because of chromebook? Thanks :)

```
board1 = ["|1|", "2|", "3|"]
board2 = ["|4|", "5|", "6|"]
board3 = ["|7|", "8|", "9|"]
print(board1)
print(board2)
print(board3)

#Output
'|1|', '2|', '3|']
['|4|', '5|', '6|']
['|7|', '8|', '9|']
```

Comment: That's *always* how a list is printed... so no, it's not because it's an online ide.

Comment: Is the missing `[` under `#Output` a typo?

Comment: _" I've never had this problem before."_ That's interesting. Can you provide an example of code you're written where printing a list _doesn't_ display brackets or commas? (note that `for item in mylist: print(item)` doesn't count as printing a list)

Comment: Printing a list will **always** do that. You should print each item separately or better, use `.join()`.

Comment: I think the issue is the missing start bracket. Do you print something before that? If an errant control code got in there, it may swallow the bracket.

Comment: Assuming this is the full program, It may well be due to the online IDE. Does the IDE try to color the output?

Comment: I'm confused. Can you clarify whether the problem is with that first bracket not printing?

Answer (score 1):

Printing a list will always show the commas and brackets.

I think you might be looking for the following:

```
print(''.join(board1))
print(''.join(board2))
print(''.join(board3))
```

That will give you the following:

```
|1|2|3|
|4|5|6|
|7|8|9|
```

Comment: Or since the OP has this tagged as 3.x: `print(*board1, sep='')` etc...

Comment: This question is technically a duplicate... you should be flagging this question instead of answering it

Comment: @JonClements - `sep='|'` ?

Comment: @tdelaney if the `|`s weren't already in the text and they were supposed to be the separator - then yes. That doesn't seem to be the case here though...

Comment: @JonClements - yeah, brain hemorrhage on my part. I was thinking in terms of removing the bars from the original list completely.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
board = [['1','2','3'],
         ['4','5','6'],
         ['7','8','9']]

for x in board: print('|%s|'%'|'.join(x))
```

Returning

```
|1|2|3|
|4|5|6|
|7|8|9|
```

Comment: OP's problem is that the open bracket is missing on the output.

Comment: That open bracket is probably a typo.